# Moiré patterns in viewport but not in render?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

When rendering overlapping meshes (I know this is bad practice, but in this case it is done purely out of curiosity) You get strange artifacts.

However, these differ from the viewport render and the <kbd>F12</kbd> render:

Here is a screenshot of the viewport render in camera view:

[image]

And here is the render:

[image]

Why are these different?

Answer (score 3):

Rendering has higher sampling per pixel, hence the precision, diminishing visible moire.

Comment: I rendered them with the same number of samples though.

Comment: Cycles?
There could be differences in clipping for instance, resulting in different precision, not sure though.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2730/599