# There is a missing part at my object when I render in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, 3d-view

This is my model in the solid view, we can see it is complete.

[image]

but in the render view or in the final render it is clipped :

[image]

[image]

here is my viewport clipping settings :

[image]

I have added a cube to the object in edit mode ; the render shows me all the form but not the cube!!!! as you can see

[image]

to clarify:

I added to the object (in edit form) a cube and move it far away. Now the render shows all the form as if the new mesh is moving some clipping plane...

[image]

Comment: It's easier to understand what your problem is if you include an image in the question.

Comment: I want to add an image or the file but I do not know how to do it, is not a camera clipping problem...

Comment: @Guillermo are you using mask modifier?

Comment: no, the only modifier used is a multirresolution

Comment: As you can see at the first picture the sofa it was made of two objects but the render only cuts 1 object, not the other.

Comment: @Guillermo can you upload the blend file use this site [pasteall.org](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/) just copy the link when it uploads

Comment: the link  http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34577

Comment: @Guillermo is this the correct file? because it is looking normal ! [render_result](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/84301)

Comment: You made a render view with the camera as it is? in Cycles? But the preview render at the 3d view?

Comment: @Guillermo yes see the render result ^

Comment: Try it the render directly at the 3d view, the problem is there.

Comment: @Guillermo it's the same no clipping ! all good ; check the file you uploaded again please

Comment: The preview render still cut the image, but when I render the active scene with the render panel doesn`t cut. The problem is on the preview render window...and only with that object!

Comment: @Guillermo "back face culling" can cause clipping but the model is fine ,so for the moment i have nothing to add ,try : reset the user settings, append the object to a new clean scene

Comment: Is not that problem, can you see the preview render fine at the 3d view? I have unchecked the "back face..." you will see that is cutting front faces on my attached images

Comment: @Guillermo yes the viewport render is fine

Comment: opening your file and pressing f12 I get this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xixOu.png No Issues on my machine. What kind of GPU are you using?

Comment: When I set the *Viewport BVH Type* to *Static* in *Render settings > performance* (see http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/32465/599 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7510/599), the couch renders correctly. Looks to me like a bug with dynamic BVH, you may want to [report this to the tracker](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1377/599).

Answer (score 2):

I don't entirely understand what you were doing with the troubleshooting, but the problem may be the camera clipping.

In the Properties Panel (<kbd>N</kbd> while cursor is in 3D view) you can change the viewport clipping.
By selecting the camera and going to the camera properties you can change the camera clipping.

[image: Camera Clipping Image]

Increasing these values will allow more of the scene to be rendered.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem and it was driving me bonkers so I started turing off the render view in my my modifiers. When I turned off my multires modifier it fixed the problem... So I just took it off and added a new one and the problem fixed.