# Part of my render stage is cut off

Tags: rendering

For some reason, there appears to be a cut-off point on my stage beyond which nothing renders. I run into it when I'm rotating the camera around my objects (I keep the "camera fixed to view" option on so I don't get lost so easily).

[image: rendering cut-off]

It's as if there was a curtain or something there, impeding the view, but I can find no obvious reason for it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe is caused by camera clipping: see if this helps: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26078/15140

Comment: Camera clipping does appear to have been the culprit — thanks. I suspect it came about because I have my default measurement units set to millimetres, so the default render area shrank accordingly.