# Rendered object Blender 2.74 can't be moved

Tags: rendering

I have rendered an object, but cannot move it around, rotate it to see all sides of the object. Is it possible to move it?

Comment: http://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/basics/quick_render.html#what-is-rendering

Comment: to get started with blender (and 3D in general) use resources on this page http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender. A good place to familiarize with the terminology and workflow is this: https://www.blender.org/support/tutorials/

Comment: I don't see why this is unclear or should be closed.  It's an honest beginner's question.

Comment: Thanks for putting me in the right direction. And yes, I'm a complete beginner and Blender is overwhelming at the start....

Answer (score 9):

Rendering (in Cycles) is the process of taking the 3-dimentional scene and calculating the light paths (called rays) bouncing through the scene to the camera.  The end result is a 2-dimentional picture of your scene, so you can't really rotate it and look around.  Just like you can't rotate and look around a photograph you took in real life.

See [my answer here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/34229/5705) for more on how Cycles works.

In order to be able to move and look around your model in perfect real time Cycles would have to perform a separate render from every possible position and angle of the camera, which is impossible.  Here a few ways to view your rendered object from multiple angles.

### 1. Viewport rendering

As [gladys pointed out](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/36478/5705) you can enable viewport rendering.  This basically re-renders the entire viewport every time you move the view.  Viewport rendering is mainly just for viewing material tweaks and the like in real time.

You can change the amount of samples used for viewport rendering in the properties panel under the *render* tab > *sampling* rollout > *samples* > *preview*.

[image]

### 2. Animating the object/camera

For a final output to showcase your object you may want to create an animation of either the camera moving around the object or the object itself moving.

Animation is done by setting *keyframes*.  A keyframe tells Blender the state you want an object to be in at a particular frame, Blender will then interpolate the object smoothly between keyframes.  To set a keyframe go to the frame you want to keyframe and hit <kbd>I</kbd> and choose the property you want to animate (i.e. location, rotation, scale, etc.).

Try checking out [this tutorial](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/turntable-animation/).

### 3. Baking

Baking is a way of saving what the surface of a rendered object looks like to an image texture which you can then apply to the object as a [shadeless shader](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8110/5705) to make the object look like it is rendered.

Unfortunately I don't have the space here to even dip into the world of texture baking but you can check out [this tutorial](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/introduction-baking-cycles/) for starters.

One thing to consider about baking is that things like gloss and transparency/refraction do not bake well as they are dependent on the viewing angle.

Comment: Thx for your help...this is great. Kat

Comment: @Kat  Glad I could help!  If this answered your question in a satisfactory manner you can mark it as accepted by clicking the little green check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you rendered it you can't move it around because it is a 2D picture. But before you render it you can look at it in the 3D viewport, by enabling the rendered display then you can rotate move etc. Make sure you use the Cycles Render engine.

[image]

Or, you can press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, to switch between solid shading and rendered shading. (in the 3d viewport)

Comment: Ok, tried this but then the object (sculptured 'frog'), turns out completely black.I'm new to Blender...so, why does it change to 2D after rendering? This defeats the purpose of creating in 3D? or do you have to animate for it to be in 3D?

Comment: do you have a light in your scene?

Comment: if you render something the output is a 2D picture or movie...but you can still work in 3D....??

Comment: Thx Gladys this has helped and am working on the lighting atm

Answer (score 1):

When a scene is rendered, the viewport shifts from the 3D view (where you can rotate) to the UV/Image editor (where you can't rotate). Simply press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to go back to the 3D view.

Or select the desired view in the bottom left menu:

[image: menu]

Shifting to the 3D view will again view your 3D object editable, but not very pretty. So arrange the camera and lights to your liking and do another render.

Comment: Thx this helps :)