# Can a surface reflect in black and white?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

So I have a gold glossy surface above a plane, and I want the plane to have a black and white reflection of the gold surface. I'm using Cycles Render and the latest version of Blender.
Here's a diagram to show you what I mean:

---

Glossy object right here -> **O**

**<** <- Camera

**_______________________** <- Glossy plane

---

I want the object to be gold, and I want its reflection on the plane to be black and white.

Comment: related to this : http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52586/how-to-change-color-of-glossy-highlights/55834#55834. If I understand well, you'll need to use the compositor for the effect you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the light path node. This node allows you to use different materials for each incoming ray type.

[image]

However, this approach is not ideal, since you have to modify the object's material and not the glossy material itself, which becomes almost unmanageable quickly.