# Weird noise when using denoise

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, denoise

[image: Weirs Noise on My Render]

i had these weird noise on my render
i had changed render settings even every object material, and it's not solved

Maybe anyone can help?

Comment: I think you enabled the Denoicer but use a low amount of samples. you can increase the number of samples. depending what you want

Comment: i do enabled the denoising, but it works fine on my other renders.

Comment: What is your node setup?

Comment: node for what? oh and 1 more thing, if i view on th camera perspective it gets blurry

Comment: The denoiser is the cause of the "blotchy " look. Use more samples, bring your resolution to 100% and rely less on denoising. Also read: [Proper Denoising?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98510/proper-denoising) and [How to avoid noisy renders in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is a materials issue.

I think what's happening is this: you have a low number of samples (it looks like it's definitely below 64). You mentioned you are using a denoiser, which works fine on other renders. However, this scene doesn't have a lot of light, so the signal-to-noise ratio is low, and the denoiser is having a hard time, producing artifacts. The solution would be to increase the number of samples. Using at least 256 might be a good idea:

[image: Samples]

Another factor that might have increased the amount of noise is that there is little direct lighting - some places need at least 2 bounces for light to reach them. The solution would be to add some more light sources. For example, you could put an emitting plane right behind the window. This would allow light to reach more places.

If this doesn't work for you, please add more information to the question. It's not easy to guess the problem from a single image :) !

Comment: ah i see, i use 256 still doesn't work though. then i use 800 and it gets better, and thank you about the light tips it helps a lot. so it gets its weird noise from denoising a lot of noise because my low number of samples huh?

Comment: @HiraMuhammad yes, that is correct. This is because there is some randomness involved when simulating light bounces, so there are some calculation errors that can be removed by taking more samples. It's a bit weird that you need 800 samples - I've never seen significant noise at 256 samples. :)