# Weird Gray Blotches Showing Up During Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, compositing-nodes

Hi I am trying to render a model of Sintel. While using the render view port shading in the 3d view the eyes looks perfectly fine:
[image]

But when I actually render it, these grey splotches show up under her eyes:

[image]

Does anyone know what may be causing this? For reference, I downloaded this model from here: https://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/66558.

Comment: You need more samples and less denoise. Read: [Proper Denoising?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98510/proper-denoising) and [How to avoid noisy renders in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles)

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering at very low sample counts. The splotches are probably created by the new denoising filter. Disabling it or incrementing your sample count should resolve this.

[image: Disable denoising here]

Comment: No, I wasn't referring to the grainy look or the fire flies, I was referring to the big gray eye-liner looking things that appear under her eyes in the second picture