# Why do I have 'glitched' areas in my render after enabling denoising?

Tags: rendering, noise-reduction, denoise

I am a newbie to blender and i found a 'Denoiser' option and decided to use it. I found out its function but it seems to create these 'glitched' areas in one of my  renders. What are they and how do i fix it?

[image: Here is my render with the 'glitches' circled in red]

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the link Duarte Farrajota Ramos posted.  I'd also like to add that I prefer the denoise settings turned down a bit, to minimize it's blur effect.

[image: denoise settings]

Comment: feel free to contribute the answers on the link.