# Any way I can remove these fireflies/noise?

Tags: noise-reduction, denoise

I have made a model of an apartment and I am trying to get rendered images from the individual rooms and in the end in orthographic view but no matter what I do there is too much fireflies or noise.
[image]
I have Clamp at 1.00, Clamp indirect at 1.00, 1000 Samples, disabled caustics and my lamps are points with x, y and z scales of 10

Here is my model, is it possible that theres too much for it to render properly?

[image]

Results where I used denoise(set clamp settings to 0):

[image]

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You say 1000 samples but the screenshot shows 32. Big difference.

Comment: Your samples are too low. 32 samples are nowhere near enough. Look at your render settings

Comment: If there is noise, you need more samples. Use the [edit] link at the bottom of your post to edit your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and show an image of the samples settings. Also plese use the tools from this site to upload images so that they appear as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: Read also: [Proper Denoising?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98510/proper-denoising/98535#98535)

Comment: Welcome to BSE! :) As most of the above comments stated, increasing the number of samples should fix it.

Comment: Thanks, turned out I was just looking at the preview render haha