# Light emission sources render as cubes

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, light

Just faced such a problem. Have kind of streetlight models in my scene (four instances of them to be exact) with the light emitting parts. Final render appears like this:
[image]

As you see, all of them appear as messy cubes. What might be happening?

Thank you all in advance.

UPD: added node scheme for light emitting mesh in a streetlight:
[image]

Comment: Can you show us your node set up for the lights?

Comment: Are you using the denoiser? Try rendering without it.

Comment: @cetagon uncheking denoising helps with cubes around streetlights but adds fireflies ((

Comment: @icYou520 added to main post

Comment: read https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98510/how-to-properly-denoise-renderings/98535#98535