# Strange artifacts on cycles render

Tags: rendering, lighting, artifacts

[image]

[image]

Do you have any idea what is causing these artifacts on my cycles render?

I'm using a sun light source to illuminate the scene. 
128 samples.

I've pasted a screenshot of the material that the artifacts are happening on

Comment: Denoising will introduce new artifacts, and is certainly not a substitute for a decent number of samples. Read: [How to properly denoise renderings?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98510/how-to-properly-denoise-renderings/98535#98535)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by raising the samples count to 400

Comment: Looks as if you were using denoising on a extremely low sample count.

Comment: I did use denoising, so it could definitely have been that. I have just never seen it before and I always use denoising. Even with low sample count

Comment: The default denoiser of Blender has some issues especially with monotone and flat surfaces, which your case does fit perfectly. The results are those clouds that form.