# Blender EEVEE pixelated render. No denoise options?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, filmic-blender

I'm a beginner in Blender and I'm trying to render a scene using Blender 2.8.

Unfortunately the result shows strong pixelation.  As far as I learned for version 2.7 (Cycles) you have to use a denoise function as [described here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98510/how-to-properly-denoise-renderings).

But I don't find a function like this for EEVEE. I have tried to use a higher number of samples. this also improves the result. But these coarse light pixels remain. Does there exist a function or method I missed to reduce pixelation?

[image]
Main Object

[image]
4K resolution - 512 Samples

[image]
HD resolution - 32 Samples

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed there are no denoise options in Blender Eevee for now.

What you can do instead is playing with the filter size, which can be found here:

[image: filter size location]

Little demo of how it works:
[image: filter size demo]

Just do some tests and see what works better on your case. Each render is different.

Alternatively, you can use the D-noise addon which will allow you to use denoising on anything using Blender's Compositor.

- [Download page](https://remingtongraphics.net/).
- [Demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HT6NBLv7w_Q)

Comment: Thanks L0Lock, that was a great suggestion! Filter size can remove some of the large white noise, but it does blur the image a bit, hence, experimentation is needed. D-Noise does a good job of removing low-level noise in EEVEE, although it doesn't automatically launch itself after rendering in the experimental builds of 2.8 (only in the official 2.8 build). :-)

Comment: Also increasing filter size can have performance benefits. For example, at 128 samples, an HD render dropped from 128 seconds to 96 seconds by increasing filter size to 1.75 pixels (from the 1.50 default size).

Answer (score 0):

Under *Output Properties* There are options to change the file format. Test the different *File Formats* I found that *AVI JPEG* rendered a clear animation for me without making render times longer (note my scene is extremely simple so this may vary).

Answer (score 0):

If you use very high power light, say 100 KW or more in your render, this incident of pixelation will happen.