# What is causing splotching on rendered image?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, lighting, hdri

I have been trying to troubleshoot this for some time now. Whenever I use an HDRI to light my scene, I get the following effect on my objects after rendering in cycles. A patchiness that I cannot seem to get rid of. This doesn't occur when I use standard lighting in my scene. Only when I light my scene with an HDRI. I am using the most recent 2.8 (at least as of this writing).

There is nothing fancy about the HDRI setup, nor is there anything unusual about the textures on the floor. The walls have a principled shader on them with nothing else applied. I am perplexed at what is causing this and would very much like to eliminate this.

Thanks ahead of time.

[image: shadowpatching]

Comment: Read: [how to avoid noisy renders in cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles/86225#86225)

Comment: Read also: [how to properly denoise renderings](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98510/how-to-properly-denoise-renderings/98535#98535)

Answer (score 2):

This kind of noise is usually caused by denoising. Lighting scenes with HDRI requires more computing and renders tend to be noisier for longer. What we see here is likely denoiser failing to cope with increased amount of noise. You should increase sample count and use light portals to combat this issue.

Comment: I will start experimenting and see how it goes. Any suggestion as to possible sample count level?

Comment: Increase it until noise and spots disappear. You can test render small patches selecting a render region in camera view with ctrl+b(ctrl+alt+b to remove region selection) in the most noisy areas that receive the least direct light. It can be anything between around 1000 to 25000 for complex interior scenes.