# How to remove lighting glitches in cycles render?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, lighting, hdri

[image]

When rendering in cycles using an HDRI, I will get black boxes that emphasize the faces in my mesh. How do I prevent this? It makes it look terrible.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/189956/broken-shadow-render-blender A bump/normal map can sometimes exacerbate the problem in the linked question.

Comment: Possible duplicate. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/144065/what-is-causing-splotching-on-rendered-image?rq=1