# Why is my render noisy/blotchy?

Tags: rendering

I'm new to Blender and wonder why, when I render the image, the image is noisy or blotchy.

The render result is shown below.
[image]
*You can see the effect clearly at the skin area.*

Can someone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Define bad.....

Comment: Hello and welcome :). I can only see some denoising artifacts (the color splotches). Increasing sample count (to like 500 samples) should help.

Comment: @Xylvier Hi, just wondering, why add `<br>` tags when pressing 'Enter' to start a new line does the same thing?

Comment: how many samples did you use? did you use denoising?

Comment: @RayMairlot:  an (un)ordered list needs the tag.

Comment: @RayMairlot Hey, as @Lukasz-40sth already mentioned, it's helping with the formatting, and even when you press 'Enter', you won't get the *clean* line-break like you get with `<br>`. Also very much the only way (*i know of*) to have images sitting right when you want them inside an ordered list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like denoising artifacts due to low render samples settings.
Go to render properties tab and increase the number of render samples.
[image: samples]
The idea is to keep the render time low and the image as good as possible. More samples will increase the render time and quality.

Comment: more info on this link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98510/how-to-properly-denoise-renderings/98535#98535