# Render has gray spots all over it

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I didn't use cycles render a long time and got a problem. If I use dark environment lighting, blender doesn't render it smooth. Maybe it happens because I'm using denoising, I don't really know.

So here is how it looks:

[image]

And the whole render look like this:

[image]

Gray spots mess up all render. I tried to search how to remove them, but still didn't find anything.

Comment: That blotchy look means Denoising artifacts. Use more samples and use less agressive settings for the denoiser.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my render noisy/blotchy?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181491/why-is-my-render-noisy-blotchy)

Answer (score 0):

You could do these things:

1. You probably have too little samples in your render. Increase your samples and re-Render.
2. Render with "Denoising Data" or if you have it enabled, render without.
   [image: with/without Denoising]
3. If you render with the old denoiser, render with the Intel Open Denoiser (The node in the compositor)
4. If that doesn`t help, please post a render without denoising.