# Transparent Object look foggy

Tags: transparency

I made an object with a thickness to be transparent but on the render it looks rather foggy and not completely transparent. Tried to make a glass casing with setting the material surface with Glass BDSF and having a roughness of 0 with screen face refraction yet i am unable to make the object completely transparent.

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

AFter removing denoise and setting the sample to 1024, it still looks foggy.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: noise... and denoise artifacts... use more samples and avoid the denoiser. Read: [why is my render noisy, boltchy](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181491/why-is-my-render-noisy-blotchy)

Comment: done as instructed, made the render look better but still has that greyish foggy issue.

Comment: Hello, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Isn’t that just the surface reflection from your white world? Try adding something to your scene to reflect or use an hdri for your world.

Comment: You are right. It is the reflection from the surface.....thank you....is there a way of reducing the reflection on the glass rendered object  instead of adjusting the IOR to make it invnsible or the roughness which makes the object look more solid....