# Black spots appear at end of render time

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

[image] [image]

Disclaimer: I looked at similar queries regarding black spots. None of which addressed the issue I am currently having.

As shown in the images, black smudges and lines appear in a variety of areas. I believe it has something to do with the emission lights I have on the ceiling. Since the black spots on the wireframe move to a different face depending on the camera view.

Things to note:
I am using cycles render with GPU support

Fixes I have tried:
I have fixed all non-manifolds. I have deleted all loose geometry. I have recalculated normals on the outside of all questionable objects.

Best,

mrabysmal

Comment: can u provide blend file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my render noisy/blotchy?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181491/why-is-my-render-noisy-blotchy)

Comment: Here is the file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=4Oe7AOmw" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/4Oe7AOmw/)

Comment: The fact that you say they’re appearing “at the end of render time“ seems to indicate it’s a compositing error. Is this possible?

Comment: ZargulTheWizard - Great point, I'll look into this, thanks

Comment: So, it turns out the Freestyle setting was checked off in the Render Settings. Thanks again for you suggestions guys. mrabysmal

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the *Freestyle* setting checkbox was ticked on in the *Render Settings*. Make sure it is disabled.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I have restored you post.  This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. Could you [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works? Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: In the future, issues about moderation or site actions should be brought up over at https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com . Thanks