# Trying to work with light and glass

Tags: glass, denoise

I'm new to Blender.

I've been working on a scene with a lighthouse, and I'm all done with the geometry. I tried an eevee render of the scene, but uh-oh! When the glass preset is applied to the window section, its not letting the cone-light pass through.

[image]

I took a look at the same scene with cycles, and ended up with this,

[image]

(I only used 8 samples because my laptop is rather weak)

Even though its just 8 samples, you get the idea. It's very noisy

Anyway, I looked around for a way to get a less noisy cycles render, and found this node setup, called Tricky-glass by the user:

[image]

I sorta understood how it worked, so I tried it.

It still didn't get rid of the noise. I, anyway, tried to do a 128 sample render with the denoiser, hoping it would fix the noise. Before the de-noising, the render was looking really pristine, except for a little noise here and there. Right after the denoising, my eyes were treated to this:

[image]

That's right, the entire geometry turned into some kind of mush.

To everyone that's about to say I'm too new to be working on this stuff- you are right!
That's why I am here. Please direct me to any helpful resources, and/or help me fix the problem mentioned  above.

My ultimate goal is to get a clean cycles render of the scene, with good-looking volumetric lighting.

My blend file (Could be messy and disorganized, pardon me for that):

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiNBYmz1aTdBgQZZtEV8uOG87Ql-?e=tdNOLn

Comment: Hello and welcome :). What exactly is your question? How to get less noisy renders? How to work with glass in Eevee? How to get rid of denoising 'mush'? :).

Comment: And no worries, nobody is gonna say you're too inexperienced to be doing this :). Everyone started somewhere.

Comment: I'd say all of them, as, like I've already said, I'm a newbie, and all three of those questions are on my mind at the moment. You don't have to explain everything tho, I'd really appreciate it even if you merely introduce me to some reliable video guides or something. Thanks ^^

Edit: ahaha, Im not embarrased or anything, but thanks :D

Comment: But yeah, My ultimate goal is to get a clean cycles render of the scene, with good-looking volumetric lighting.

Comment: Okay then. You'll need to use 500-1000 render samples before even trying denoiser :). The more samples, the better denoising results. And volumetrics often require > 2000 samples.

Comment: Is it really as simple as bumping up the sample count? Thanks!

Also, I think my take-away from this should be that My geometry won't be distorted by the denoiser, if the sample count is high enough <--- is this correct? 

One last question - how do I get light to pass through the glass in Eevee, just like in cycles?

Comment: Yes, the distorted image is a result of too few samples for denoiser (it has to guess a lot). Regarding Eevee and glass, use the search field, it was asked many times before :).

Comment: You are an absolute legend mate, thanks for the help!

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98510/how-to-properly-denoise-renderings

Comment: @Timaroberts thanks for those, it was quite helpful ^_^

Comment: Just enable transparency under eevee settings.

Comment: @JachymMichal yes, another user up above directed me to the link, and it was kinda helpful, tho I'm sure it'll take me some more time before I understand it all and everything falls into place in my head. Thanks tho!