# getting a weird raisin texture on liquid texture?

Tags: rendering

im getting a weird raisin texture on my liquid from blender guru's tutorial. I've followed it 100% through so far and I can't find a way to fix this.

[image: Image Here:]

Comment: Is this with the viewport denoiser active?  It looks like denoiser artifacts

Comment: do you mean is this in the viewport or rendered? if so this is rendered.

Comment: This gives context - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98510/how-to-properly-denoise-renderings?r=SearchResults

Comment: I added more samples and it works now! I completely forgot you could add samples