# Blue Stuff in my render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

[image]

[image]
I was rendering this scene (on cycles) to test out the lighting in my upcoming animation project but for some reason the render had blue stuff all over it, I tried to see if it had to do anything with the glossy floor reflection, or maybe the dark setting of the lighting. But I still got the same results.
I also tried the same scene for eevee and the blue stuff was not there.

[Here is the .blend file](https://www.mediafire.com/file/mh332ctp1ode3y6/Bar-Talk.blend/file)

Comment: Please add a download link to your file so that we can assess what is wrong with it using https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Looks like reflections getting smudged by a denoiser - https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/98535/110840

Answer (score 1):

Not Shure with not so much info. But for me it looks like caustics. if you want to get rid of them just disable them in Cycles render under Render>Light Paths>Caustics> click on boxes that may be on by Default. I hope it did help.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I am still getting the same results. Thanks anyways, if you think you need more info to help me out here, ill be more then happy to provide it.