# My characters skin looks Caustic in Cycles and the Shirt Texture is missing

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, eevee-render-engine

My characters skin looks Caustic in Cycles and the Shirt Texture is missing.

Cycles Render
[image: Here is the Cycles render]

EEVEE render
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? - https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/98535/110840

Comment: Hi, could you share the file using this site:
https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Yes it did! Thank you very much!