# Colors smear into a puddle in render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, light, color

I'm very new to blender and I'm making my first kitchen scene. When I'm trying to render the scene I have stumbled upon something weird. On both the cabinet drawers and doors the colors seems to smear into a puddle (look pictures). I'll render the image with both cycles engine and eevee so you can see the difference.

I'm running the render with 128 samples and are using OptiX for denoising. I don't think this is a issue but I have a total of 12 max light bounces(Heard this is a lot but render time is no issue).

I wonder if I have done something weird with the material, lighting or my render settings, thanks for any help!

[image: Cycles engine render]
[image: Eevee engine render]

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE.  How many samples are you running and what denoising method are you using?  Please [edit] your post with a little more info. :)

Comment: There I updated the post, hope that's enough info :)

Comment: Hard to say for sure, but you might try the denoiser in the compositor instead, because you can supply Normal data - https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/229227/110840  Do these doors and drawers have a bevel on the edge?