# Cycles render problem again

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, artifacts

I know this issue pops up periodically.
But I still haven't found a solution.
The problem is on this picture.

Other projects render great even with 128-64 samples.
I realized that the problem is not with samples at all.
I tried big numbers, but it's useless.
I was thinking about denoiser, but:
denoiser off - it gives awful noise;
OptiX gives this result;
openimagedenoise gives smth like this but worse.

Few hours ago everything was good. The project rendered without any problem.
Well, I created a couple of shape changing objects.
But logically they can't increase the noise.
In addition, I tried to render without them.
The same result.

[image: Cycles Render problem]

Comment: Is it possible to add a "good before" screenshot from any render file that you saved?  Or else better describe what you do not like?  Is it the noise on the concrete/brick walls?

Comment: Suspect that the number of lights in the scene is causing harsher probabilistic noise and that's throwing the denoiser off.  Which denoiser are you using?  Are you using the denoiser found below the Render Samples setting, or have you enabled Denoising Data for use in the Compositor?

Comment: Perhaps related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/229227/110840

Comment: @james_t 
Ground is simple Principled BSDF with Noise texture.
Asphalt is an image texture.
And there is another simple BDSF one the house walls

Comment: How does the lighting differ, between 'good' and 'bad' ?

Comment: @RobinBetts  
Well, after 2 days of break I found out that the problem could be in material textures.
Ground - noise texture with color ramp. 
Asphalt is an image texture as i sad earlier with a lot of nodes (roughness, displacement, normal and even mix shader).
Anyway this is strange. It shouldn't make such mess.
I rendered some other pictures from other projects with animation too. They have much more  geometry,  materials and objects. Everything look good even in low frame render.

Comment: @AllenSimpson I use OptiX. It gives better result.  No denoiser in Compositor. I tried it. It doesn't help. After i reseted materials everything looks great. This is strange. 
As i sad i rendered a lot of frames from other projects wich are much more complex and everything is fine even in low frame render.

Comment: When i add more light it looks ok, but i don't need so much light. It's a night scene.

Comment: Not really my area, but it might help others to say what _kind_ of lights those are, and whether [Multiple Importance](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/optimizations/reducing_noise.html#multiple-importance-sampling) needs to be set

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to troubleshoot problems like this is to create a *Render Region* with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>.

From the camera view, draw a region around a small area you know is currently having the problem.  Now an <kbd>F12</kbd> full render will only render this area, and you can afford to render many more samples and quickly try things out.  The advantage is that you don't have to do anything else to simplify your scene, which could affect your perception of the problem.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to remove the region, or just draw a region around the whole camera frame and it will resize to a full frame view.  (I do this almost all the time anyway because it crops the viewport and speeds it up some.)