# How to preview just one zone with cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I've watched this tutorial where i think the author selects an specific zone to preview with cycles. I can't get with the keys to do that. Is it possible what I'm saying?

https://youtu.be/PoSvCn1Jl6g?t=240   min 4

[image: Preview with image noise]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *Render Region*, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> in *Object Mode*.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to clear the selection.

In the manual, this is found on the page for [View Regions](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/regions.html).

Comment: Thanx for the answer. I have another issue. Is it normal to have a preview with "noise" when you do "render region"? I have added an image in the bio.

Comment: That looks quite normal.  To mitigate that you can run more samples or use a denoiser.  Here are instructions for blender 3 - https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/229227/110840

Comment: Thank you so much!