# Viewport rendering (shift+Z) is darker than in final render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, 3d-view, light

I just purchased an interior scene from chocoviz for the cycles render engine.

When I do a test render in the viewport it renders, but is much darker than in the final render.

What could be the cause of this issue? How can I resolve it?

Comment: Look into differences between them. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2728/what-are-the-technical-differences-between-f12-render-and-viewport-preview and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/985/cycles-viewport-render-different-than-f12-render. I think you meant `Shift`+`Z` shortcut.

Comment: Are you sure no post production was applied to the render?

Comment: There are a lot of possibilities. Unfortunately, since this is a purchased scene, you will not be allowed to upload it, so there's only the option of screenshots or blind advise. Possible causes: 1) some lights or mesh lights are made invisible in the Viewport, but are set to be renderable, 2) the scene uses local layers, for rendering other layers with light sources are enabled which you currently don't see, 3) the brightening happens in the compositor, 4) ...

Comment: Check if you enabled ambient occlusion in "world" panel.

Comment: Perhaps you could contact chocofur since it is their commercial product. We can't help as effectively as they can because we cannot see the .blend file, and it is their job to provide customer support after all.

Comment: There could be something in the compositing tab?

Answer (score 2):

In interior scenes and in scenes that have lots of translucent materials it is common for them to be dark until the camera has sampled enough light. If it still seems too dark after 100 samples try duplicating the lights and disabling the render setting on them. This will most likely give better results if not the most accurate.

Comment: I agree. Sounds like sampling is the culprit here.

Answer (score 0):

This might not answer OP question, but...

There are [some limitations](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7510/why-is-rendered-viewport-faster-than-rendering-individual-frames) regarding to viewport rendering

I think the main problem is in viewport, they lack of light bounces. So adding a light (but discard on render) seems to solve the problem.