# How do I enable motion blur for Mantaflow fluids?

Tags: fluid-simulation, motion-blur

How do I enable motion blur for Mantaflow fluids? I'm using 2.82

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you bake the mesh for your liquid on the domain, make sure "use speed vectors" is checked in the mesh tab.  If it wasn't then you will have to bake the mesh again.  After that, it will automatically render motion blur if you are using Cycles.

Comment: I can't get it to show in the viewport with Cycles. How do I do that?

Comment: Motionblur in viewport with cycles is not supported apparently:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8520/why-cant-i-see-motion-blur-in-the-viewport-cycles