# Background hdr image is covering up model when rendered

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Making Gold object but background hdr image is covering up model when I render. I am using cycles render and am trying to make my object have a gold appearance so I uploaded an hdr image in the world tab but now this image is the only thing I can see when I render. What should I do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you upload some screenshots or a .blend?

Comment: First picture my model, second picture what happens when i render

Comment: If you add other objects, are they rendered?

Comment: There are many possible causes I can think of, but without more information I can't say which it is in this case. The easiest way for us to troubleshoot your issue is with a .blend..

Comment: @gandalf3 Could you put them out there anyway, this user clearly doesn't want to upload the .blend.

Comment: There's obviously nothing wrong with not uploading your .blend, but it would help a lot. You could delete everything except the parts necessary to reproduce the issue, if that helps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things which could cause this, but here are some of the most likely ones (not including the ones already mentioned by GiantCowfilms)

- A Modifier disabled in the viewport could be hiding/messing up the object(s) only in the render.
- As GiantCowfilms already suggested, it could be a renderlayer issue. **Having all layers selected does not mean your object will be in a renderlayer**, the layers specified under *layer* are the ones which are used in rendering:

  [image]

  In the above case, only layer three will be rendered (objects on layers 1 and 2 will not appear).
- *Use surfaces* could be disabled:

  [image]
- A transparent material be used somewhere, such as the *material override* slot.
- A problem with the compositing setup could be excluding your objects from the composited result.

<sub>There are all sorts of unlikely scenarios which could cause this, so there's really no possible way to list them all..</sub>

---

## Troubleshooting

To help troubleshoot this, here are some things you can try:

- Are the objects rendered in viewport render (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>)?

  If it does, then this suggests it's something on [this list](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2728/599).
- If you add a new object, is it rendered?

  If it is, then that suggests it's something object specific (not a renderlayer/compositing problem)

Comment: Hold on it worked for a second then the screen goes black on the render at the very end...

Answer (score 1):

Without a .blend it is hard to say for certain what the issue is. 
Here are some possible causes:

1. You're rendering on the wrong render layer.
2. You turned off your objects render visibility:
   [image]
3. You disabled your objects visibility to the camera in the ray visibility tab.
   [image]

Comment: Ray visibility is on too :( How could i be rendering on the wrong layer? Both the hdr image and the layer I am on is active

Comment: @user5344 Could you post a .blend, I can't think of any more causes.