# Why are objects appearing as a "ghostly" image after rendering?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, shaders

I'm fairly new to Blender, but I hope there's a simple solution to this issue.

In Cycles I'm trying to make a composite of (soon-to-be) animated objects and video footage.

I've used nodes to apply *transparent* and *translucent* shaders to the four circle meshes (UV unwrapped with textures) and put in a simple cube for comparison's sake. (An emission shader has also been applied to the largest, yellow circle.)

This is the 3D view set to *solid* shading, with a background image.

[image: viewport]

Here's the rendered view:

[image: rendered image]

Why is everything so "ghostly" and pale? No shader has been applied to the cube, and the circles appear much dimmer than I need.

Is there a way to fix this? How can I make the circles appear more "solid" without losing the transparency and translucency I need? It would be ideal if it could look more like the preview in the viewport shading,

[image]

but I hear the viewport shading result and the final render result are never the same...

Any thoughts?

cycles material
[image: Object mesh nodes]

compositor nodes
[image: compositor nodes]

Comment: The actually are the same a good amount of the time. There are only a few minor differences, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2728/599. Do you have motion blur enabled? Or any compositing nodes?

Comment: can you post a screen shot of your compositor nodes?

Comment: Thanks for looking into my issue, gandalf3 and cegaton.

Gandlaf3: I'll look into your link.

Cegaton, please see my edited entry for the screencaps of my nodes.

Comment: can you upload your blend file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using an [*Alpha over* node](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Composite_Nodes/Types/Color#AlphaOver_Node) instead of an add node:

[image]

The add node literally *adds* the pixel values of one image to the other image. This means that not only will you have both images visible at once, but you could end up with pixels brighter than 1.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers, both of you.

Gandalf3, the "Alpha Over" is what I was looking for. Many thanks.

Comment: If this answer satisfactorily answered your question, consider marking it as accepted by clicking the checkmark next to it :)