# How can i fully remove fire flies?

Tags: light

I turned off Reflective Caustics and Refractive Caustics but my image is still full of fireflies how can i fully remove them?[image]

Comment: That looks mostly like noise to me, try cranking up the samples.  254 isn't much for an interior scene.

Comment: The samples are at 254 but its still coming out rather noisy.

Comment: That's what I am saying, interior scenes are pretty noisy so 254 isn't much, try increasing it.

Comment: That is noise. The image on the bottom left is just a preview render with only 10 samples (see that 10/10 on top of the image?) You can render the image pressing F12 or increase the number of saples fro the preview

Comment: Note that the render samples are set to 254, while what is shown on screenshot is preview render (`Shift`+`Z`), controlled by preview samples; so that image is rendered using 10 samples. To see how image looks exactly on 254 either render it or increase preview samples.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2728/what-are-the-technical-differences-between-f12-render-and-viewport-preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to reduce them as much as possible,

-set clamp indirect and direct to values near 1 or 2
-use standar lamps as much as possible, geometry lit obejects tends to generate more noise, on most situations.
-try also using branched path tracing to test which rays are the ones generating the noise.

Answer (score 2):

What I see in this image is noise, not fireflies. What you are seeing is a preview render at only 10 samples, which is nowhere near enough for an interior scene. Simply try rendering with more samples. You may need 1000 to 5000 samples to completely remove all the noise.