# Lighting changes during animation

Tags: rendering, lighting

I made an animation to test out a cell fracture add on but encountered the lighting was changing frame to frame. The lighting set up is three planes as shown in the photo:[image]

Here is the animation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HP3vA2Yp8Aw&feature=youtu.be

Here is the .blend file: [image]

I'm not sure what is happening here?

Comment: If you post your.blend using [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) others will be able to examine your work, so you'll be more likely to receive help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is causing my frames to "flicker" after being rendered?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93379/what-is-causing-my-frames-to-flicker-after-being-rendered)

Comment: @cegaton I believe Youtube is currently experiencing issues, I am getting that on multiple videos

Comment: Sorry this is my first time asking a question. I have put the link in the question