# Why these images in mode (rendered ) previous and in mode render are not the similar?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, makehuman

Here is a rendering of human character, the top image is from the view3D window using "Display render preview" and the bottom image is the result of rendering. I remark that these images are not identical as expected! Normally, I want to get the top image in both cases? Any explanation ?

[image]

Comment: Try pressing the "Zero" key to look through the camera.

Comment: Related:[What are the technical differences between F12 render and viewport preview?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2728/what-are-the-technical-differences-between-f12-render-and-viewport-preview)