# See results of image editor in realtime

Tags: uv-image-editor

How do I work in blender while seeing the results of the image editor in realtime? It seems the only way I can see the end result is by rendering a still or animation... but I'd like to see a new still every time I move the animation to a new frame, for example.

[image]

Comment: This won't work for simple reason - to see the result you wish it has to be rendered. Even it was, render will overwrite the previous result. Even if you used Render slots to avoid that (up to 8 slots available) different rendered frames won't be seen while you move timeline cursor, rather than in UV / Image editor. Also please include info about whether you want to get result updated with compositing nodes or not. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2728/1245

Comment: Basically I want to see the results of image fx I have going on with the nodes. It's very difficult to work with animation if I can't see what the image fx is doing to my scene. It's almost like I'm trying to use Blender like Adobe After effects, I think it is simply not going to work... basically, every time I was to move the frame cursor, I want the "render" to be triggered. It would be a very simple fix for Blender. Just re-render every time I move the frame cursor.

Comment: It won't be quite expected behaviour it seems.. Rendered image may be a pain to re-render hence it is something user is awaited to decide. What you ask is possible but only for modeling edits (objects in the scene), not for scrabbing timeline. However if you want *only* compositor changes it would be much more efficient to render whole animation to a stills *without* compositing, import that as image sequence and edit that one. Do note that you will want to render to something like OpenEXR to get expected compositng results.

Comment: Right, well I need to change the way I work. This is the first time I used Blender and I had to make changes to my objects' positions and animations while checking the results after the image processing. So, thanks! I'll have to figure out what I want to do from here. I finished the project btw.

Answer (score 0):

If you place your cursor in the *3D Viewport* and key <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>, it will put you into *Rendered View*. You can key <kbd>Z</kbd> twice to return to *Solid View*.

*Solid View:*

[image]

*Rendered View:*

[image]

Comment: updated the question with an image, this suggestion didn't solve the problem.