# Different render time in preview and final render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I'm rendering long animations and it's important to me to save time. In the preview, a frame is rendered in 30 seconds, but if I render the animation, the render time of one frame increases to 2 minutes. Why does this happen and how can I get the final render with time of the preview render?
[image: Viewport Render Screenshot]

[image]

Comment: Do you use the same amount of samples for preview and render? (You can find and adjust the values in the `Sampling` section of the `Render` tab)

Comment: Yep. So, preview render working faster even at a glance.

Comment: Could you upload the .blend file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ please?

Comment: I didn't find a solution yet. I deleted everything in the scene, disables motion blur, light bounces, resolution and tile size ... and it's an even bigger factor with CPU. Now I don't know what else to try.

Comment: I'm surprised) I thought that preview time must be equivalent to final render time. But thank you for trying.

Comment: No ,the render time of preview and final render vary depending on the settings for rendering (number of samples, and other factors) please read this post to understand the difference:http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2728/what-are-the-technical-differences-between-f12-render-and-viewport-preview