# Why is the preview render slower than the final render?

Tags: rendering, gpu

Firstly, sorry if that's a stupid question. I'm kinda noob :P
The thing is that "normal" rendering with GPU is slower than rendering in preview. I made sure that the resolution in which I render is the same as in the preview but it's still slower as if it was rendered with CPU.

Comment: I'm confused - are you saying that rendering with GPU is slower than rendering with the CPU or slower than doing a preview render (with OpenGL)?

Comment: OpenGL Render will be faster because it uses a different rasterization technique that uses a lot of shortcuts. Also, the materials aren't applied to it. The rendered viewport shading is also different from a final render because it sacrifices a lot of features for speed. Most notably, it uses dynamic bounding volume hierarchy to accelerate it and is one of the reasons the sampling looks weird in this viewport shading mode.

Comment: @UnholySheep
Slower that preview render.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I mean rendering using Cycles.

Comment: @hiya If you need to add more information you can use the [edit] link below your question.

Comment: The preview render is optimized for speed but takes shortcuts, and usually is set up to render with less samples. read: [**what are the technical differences between f12 render and viewport preview**](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2728/what-are-the-technical-differences-between-f12-render-and-viewport-preview)

Comment: If the question is about having the exact same sample count for preview and final render, and also roughly the same resolution, then the answer is that final render uses tile based rendering. Tiles of a size around 256x256 pixels usually perform best on GPU. That means, make the tile size bigger OR smaller, the final render (in most cases) will come out a bit slower. Now: the preview render basically samples the whole image as one tile. That means sampling one huge tile the size of your vieport space in pixels. Since that is a bit more inefficient on GPU, the render speed decreases.

Answer (score -3):

Use rendering CPU to GPU, it can be faster then GPU

Change Render Setting
Use this[enter link description here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7485/enabling-gpu-rendering-)

Answer (score -4):

If you are rendering more colors, change to sampling to 200 to 10