# Cycles: noise in dark sections

Tags: cycles-render-engine, noise-reduction

[image: Noise]

I'm having trouble with noise.
Its mostly in dark sections, it doesen't look to bad in the picture but that's with 3000 path tracing samples. It's rendering at 1920x1080 and using  filmic blender at medium high contrast.

[image: 200 path tracing samples]

Comment: From the first screenshot you have Preview set to 3000 but Render set to only 200. Is that intentional? The render in the second screenshot looks to be only 200 samples.

Comment: Yes this is intentional. It was set to 3000 to show the noise.

Comment: render at a higher number of samples.

Comment: This is for an animation, More than 3000 sample might be to long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the standard advice of making mesh light sources brighter and spot lamp sizes larger applies here, these would be the most "natural" ways of reducing noise[1].

If the Starmap is emitting light as an HDR, it might be a good idea to try Multiple Importance Sampling in Cycles.

But I do agree with you that one should expect a less noisy image at 3000 samples. Filmic blender actually doesn't affect Cycles contrary to popular belief.

Also, have a look at airenderer.com. It's a renderer that takes a noisy image (probably 200 samples is enough here) and gives you a more rendered result. It doesn't every type of scene well, but this looks like the type of scene this was built for.

sources: [1]blenderguru.com

Comment: In the images you posted you are not rendering at 3000 samples for the final render, but only at 200. Usually you want the preview number of samples to be low, so that you can manipulate your scene and make an evaluation of lighting and texturing and then render at a higher sample for the final render. The render view on the viewport should only be used as a reference. More information on this link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2728/what-are-the-technical-differences-between-f12-render-and-viewport-preview