# Brightness of environment texture diminished at last step of render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I'm rendering a scene in which a reflective plane (with ocean modifier) stretches to the horizon, and I have an image of a sunset for my environment texture.

My problem comes in the the last five seconds of rendering any given frame; the overall brightness of the image suddenly becomes dimmed as the render completes.  There is also a very slight glow around objects against the texture, like an alpha channel (although my transparency is turned off).

Attached image: TOP RENDER is calculating by going to Render > Render Image.  The BOTTOM RENDER is the viewport with view mode set to rendered.

Render settings:
PNG, RGB
1920x1080
100 samples
No clamping
Motion blur shutter: 0.5

Thanks

[image: attached image]

Comment: The render output is showing that it is the "composite" layer. What's going on in the compositor?

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2728/what-are-the-technical-differences-between-f12-render-and-viewport-preview

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. We don't know how you set up your project or your textures or render settings.