# Screen Space Reflections in EEVEE

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I am struggling with understanding screen space reflections in EEVEE.

I am aware of the excellent answer to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121203/objects-shadows-and-reflections-not-rendering-in-eevee/122086#122086), however, this only talks about when an object is off screen entirely.

Maybe it is the same point (if so, I apologise), but can someone confirm for me that this is actually the correct behavior? The partial reflection seems so odd that I am having trouble believing this is how it is supposed to work.

Is the entire bottom face of the cube really supposed to be missing?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I haven't dig into the theory of the implementation yet, but I have a feeling that Screen Space Reflection is just mirroring the already rendered pixel (aka what you actually see on the screen, the screen space data).

I think **that's the intended behaviour**. It's an heavy approximation that on the other hand gives nice and fast results, expecially for the objects that touch the ground.

You'll have to use a Reflection Plane to get the reflections of the occluded geometries.

[image]

Comment: Your feeling is correct, it works indeed like that.

Comment: @JaroslavJerrynoNovotny thanks fot the confirm. I tried to find some straight evidence/source to quote, but it's harder than I thought.

Comment: @Carlo Thanks. I'll do some more experimenting with light probes. I got them to work once, but for some reason now when I bake indirect lighting they don't work at all. Sure I'm missing a setting or something. Cheers.

Comment: @Carlo My issue was not realising that light probes don't work in LookDev, only in Rendered view.