# Rendering extra 100px outside specified resolution and cropping down for final output?

Tags: rendering

With Screenspace reflections on I want to keep my edge fading at 0.075, but prevent it from fading the edges of the screen when zoomed in on a reflective surface.

So currently I get this really nasty effect on my window material (top left) when it's not fully in frame:

[image]

Is there a way to render the borders just outside the camera's vision, and then crop that to my actual desired output resolution to get around this? Is this possible with render borders?

So although I want a 1920x1080 image, I want to render, say, 2120x1280 (an extra 100px around the borders) and then have blender crop it back to what it should be and save this as the render output.

Edit: This is not a duplicate of the referred to question. The problem has nothing to do with faces not facing the camera and not being reflected. There's almost no reflection in the glass but this is intentional. I just wanted to show the black edge effect in a previously rendered frame.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126602/screen-space-reflections-in-eevee

Comment: ^ Sorry that's completely irrelevant to my issue. This is regarding the edge fading, and besides I know it's a limitation of the renderer. I want to know if it's possible to pad the render frame and then crop it to remove the black edge effect.

Comment: I could do this manually by increasing the resolution, altering the lens angle, rendering, then cropping the image down to 1920x1080 manually (for each and every frame), but I figured there is probably a better way of doing it within Blender's framework.

Comment: Not in one step as far as I know, but you might be able to batch crop with the compositor in a separate scene. 
 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52231/rendering-a-stereoscopic-image-in-blender-2-77/57870

Comment: I could write a script that did this, but I don't know how I'd take an existing camera, possibly animated, and expand the render region to more than 100% without messing with the field of view - which would create a noticably different image. I want to see the exact same field of view but zoomed out so that when it's flattened, it has 100px padding on the edges.