# Cycles v. Eevee mirror reflections

Tags: rendering

[image]Is there any way to get Eevee to reflect like Cycles does? My settings for the scene are identical. I took a screen grab of the F12 render window in Cycles then again in Eevee (see picture) - no other changes were made. Only part of the sphere is reflected in Eevee but in Cycles it's perfect. 
The background image is an HDR and no other lighting is used but I did try lighting the dark side of the sphere in Eevee but it made no difference so I cancelled the light source (point).

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126602/screen-space-reflections-in-eevee

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121203/objects-shadows-and-reflections-not-rendering-in-eevee/122086#122086