# Eevee screen space refraction weird black shadow

Tags: eevee-render-engine, shadows

I noticed there's a weird second shadow in a plane with screen space refraction in Eevee. How to remove that weird duplicated shadow?

Weird duplicate shadow in Eevee:
[image]

Correct result in Cycles:
[image]

In Blender:
[image]

Blender file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HmVcczNBuuX9q1ymHQXuHn6piSOjldJC/view?usp=sharing)

Using Blender 2.83.4

Edited:
Although setting `Refraction Depth` to small value such as 0.1m works removing the unwanted "shadow", but it also removes the refraction effect. To get refraction effect, the value has to be more than 1m to see noticeable effect. Putting another object on top of the plane with refraction along 1m value, the "shadow" is back.

[image]

New edited Blender file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZaPYJIY1_pASH_SP6ZsH4gDMftZk6m5v/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have set *Refraction Depth* to zero.
It is not clear to me if values below are correct, but you get rid of the "shadow" thing.

[image]

---

### Glass Plate

Go to *Properties Editor > Material > Settings* > **Refraction Depth** and play with value.
In your case 0,1-0,4 m works. It seems to be distance from glass to Monkey.

[image]

### Deep Water

It seems to be more complicated ... it depend if it should be glass plate or deep water. In second case probably make sense increase to 4 m, that is distance from surface to bottom.

[image]

In that case you have to also increase Thickness under SSR Render Properties.

[image]

---

**My theory notes behind**

The "weird shadow" (as you call it) is a part of bottom plane surface that is not visible from current point of view on background plane. You can see actually through the plane what is behind in that place.

*You can actually confirm that by your self. Check where is the issue located on glass plane and switch to wire mode. Real monkey object is placed exactly on the same place on background plane from current point of view .*

I guess by default this is some kind if refraction clipping to keep Eevee real-time.

Similar thing happens when you try set reflected floor with object howering above - in a floor is not reflected bottom part of mesh that is hidden from point of view. Like here – [Screen Space Reflections in EEVEE](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126602/screen-space-reflections-in-eevee)

**See also ...**

[Eevee Limitations](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/limitations.html)
[Manual - Refraction Depth](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/render/eevee/materials/settings.html#screen-space-refraction)

Comment: Did you mean u solved it using glass distortion? I'm also using Glass BSDF for the refraction floor. From the screenshot, it seems worse than my case. Could you explain further?

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear. Edited

Comment: Cool it works! Managed to remove the weird "shadow" by setting the refraction depth to 0.1m. @vklidu Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Comment: i noticed setting Refraction Depth < 1m removed, but it does not have refraction effect anymore. By setting > 1m, and putting the object on top of the refraction plane, the "shadow" comes back. I updated my post to include the new Blender file and screenshot

Comment: 0,1 works like thin glass plate. I don't think you can achieve something like that. See links at the end of my A. I will have to edit answer anyway ...