# Reflective material don't reflect a mesh

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, reflection

I am quite new to Blender. I tried to set up a scene with a little character I modelised with a floor and an hdr. My problem is that the parts of my character which has a reflective material reflect the hdr but not the floor.
Here is my viewport with viewport shading. I use eevee.
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121203/objects-shadows-and-reflections-not-rendering-in-eevee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to the render properties >>> Screen space reflections

[image]

Comment: I tried that but that reflected the other parts of the character but not the floor

Comment: Then, propably something is wrong, because i already try an it is working, i'm adding an image to the answer. Share your file to take a look at it

Comment: Ok I tried again and it's working, thank you. But why are the reflexions of the mesh so bad ? the quality is not as high as the hdr reflexion for example

Comment: Probably because the sampling count is really low, mine is just 16