# Eevee rendered image weird frame-edge problem

Tags: eevee-render-engine

i'm trying to render a frame and everything looks good besides the upper frame edge that makes the blindfolds window just get cut mid-way.

Anyone have any idea why is this happening?

i've attached a viewport and rendered image.

thanks in advance!

[image: Viewport Image]

[image: Rendered Image]

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Couldn't that be clipping distance in your camera settings?

Comment: @JachymMichal is the clipping distance different between viewport and render?

Comment: @TheBeautifulOrc Yes, it's adjusted separately for viewport camera and render cameras :).

Comment: @JachymMichal Thank you! I tried changing the clip Start to 0.1cm (it was on 10cm) but the problem persists. 
Furthermore, If i move the blindfolds to the inner part of the window - it stills cut them the same way (so maybe distance is not the problem)

Comment: Hey @Eolo :). I'll take a look if you share the .blend file. I've never encountered this behavior before.

Comment: @JachymMichal I've managed to solve the problem by turning"overscan" on as suggested here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121203/objects-shadows-and-reflections-not-rendering-in-eevee

thank you very much for your help