# Lights and Emission lights following the camera/view angle

Tags: 3d-view, light, emission

Hope you can help with this weird issue. I'm pretty new to blender so please go easy on me.

So as you can see in the attached images, the main spot light, only works when the camera/view is facing it. You can also see the lights/reflections on the model changing when the camera/view is moved.

This happens in both Eevee and Cycles

I am using a HDRI map so i'm not sure if this is causing light issues.

Any help on understanding why this is happening would be great, i just need normal light emission and not something following the camera/view.

[image: Lights reflecting in different directions]
[image: Example 2]

Peter

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121203/objects-shadows-and-reflections-not-rendering-in-eevee/122086#122086

Comment: Thanks Duarte!

Really useful information here, much appreciated. But i have the same issue in the Cycles render also. It's as if the lights only work when they're pointing towards to camera. The emission lights you'd think should reflect off every point of an object like a real light instead of a small section, most noticeably in the first image.

If this is simply the limitations of blender then i guess i'll have to deal with it.

Thanks

Comment: If it is happening in Cycles as well then it must be other different issue. Impossible to tell from a screenshot alone, but your lamp seems to be too close to the surface, maybe it size is intersecting with it and causing issues