# Two Problems with a Nixie Tube: Glass and Glow

Tags: modeling, materials, eevee-render-engine, glass, emission

I want to make a convinceable model of an IN12B Nixie tube.
The model should render with eevee.
I added an example file.

[image] [image]

Two problems:
The glass looks somehow "plasticy" and is a lot of settings hacked together awfully in a mess.
The "neon glow" isn't what it should be:
Neither there is a reflexion of the glow on the glass or the plate nor it there this distinctive
faint glow of the neon gas around the wire.

Here is an image, how it should look like:
http://danyk.cz/digitrony_en.html
and search for "Soviet nixie tube IN-12B" (sorry, there are too many example on that page).

How can I acchieve more convinceable materials and effects?

Here is a rendering from the 3DView:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Could you please add your current render result? Just to illustrate the problems.

Comment: I have added a picture from the 3DView (eevee)

Answer (score 2):

Eevee can handle all this quite well with basic materials.

1. *Glass BSDF* (or Principled BSDF) for glass
2. *Emission* shader for the light
3. Check ✓ *Bloom* to simulate the neon gas volumetrics

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to restrict "Bloom" to the tube? Otherwise the complete scene would be affected, which is not wanted.

Comment: Hey :). I don't think you can limit 'Bloom' to a specific area. But the Compositor has a 'Glare node' which gives a similar effect and can be masked.

Comment: The pictures you show above are your test renders, aren't they. Would you mind to add them? It is due to the second problem I have with all this (see above): The neo is glowing, if you look at it directly...but there is no reflection of the emitted light from the glass tube or off the tube inner parts, which are simple dull metal surfaces -- as shown on the page I linked in my initial post. Turning up the emission power follows the color changes of hot metal (it become more white  when glowing stronger). Neon only has two promiment emissison liness in the sprectrum and stay at the same color.

Comment: Hello :). Eevee has some unfortunate [limitations on mesh lights](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/99631/78972) and also [limited reflections](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/121203/78972). If you're going for realism, Cycles might be a better choice.

Comment: You can also hit me up on our SE chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/433213/jachym-michal

Comment: Knock, knock, Neo?                            I am there (at the chat room)... :) :)