# Eevee reflections clipping at the edge in render but not viewport

Tags: eevee-render-engine

In rendered view(left) displays like how it should, however when rendered the reflection is clipped at the bottom(right). THe plane has a principled bsdf with 0 roughness and screen space refraction turned off. Screen space reflections are of course turned on, half res trace is turned off. I tried reducing edge fading to 0 but it didn't change anything. Anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121203/objects-shadows-and-reflections-not-rendering-in-eevee

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about overscan

Answer (score 2):

Turning on Overscan in Render Properties > Film solved the problem. Still not sure why camera view is different from the render though

Comment: Thank you, I struggled a lot with the ability to see the emission reflections in the render to look the same as in viewport and overscan helped.